# Play sound on Safari (iOS) and Chrome (Android) using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, mobile-safari

I want to be able to play sound on HTML page using JavaScript when some event happens.

Basically I want to get data from server using AJAX and then if it is something specific, then play sound.
It works great on PC browsers, but I have issues making it work on Safari (iOS) and Chrome (Android). I read that to play sound on Chrome (I guess Safari also), this needs to be triggered by some user event (gesture, click, etc.). So here is my SIMPLIFIED code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="7" />
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="playSound()" id="button">Click me</button>
<script>
    window.setInterval(function(){
        parent.document.getElementById('button').click();
    }, 5000);
    function playSound() {
        var audio = new Audio('http://www.soundjay.com/button/beep-01a.wav');
        audio.play();
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I thought this workaround will work (trigger click event using JS), but still no sound.
One additional thing is that I want to AJAX code every few seconds and even **when phone is BLOCKED**. I found this solution (and applied my changes from previous try):

background.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3" />
</head>
<body>
<script>
parent.run_function_from_core_page();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

In index.html:

```
<iframe src="background.html" style="display:none;"></iframe>
```

But again, works great on PC, but no sound on either Chrome mobile and Safari mobile.
Any suggestions? Is that even possible?